# Solve the equation with radicals: $x^2- x \sqrt[4]{2} (1+ \sqrt[4]{2} ) + \sqrt[4]{8} = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, radicals

Solve this equation :

$ x^2- x \sqrt[4]{2} (1+ \sqrt[4]{2} ) + \sqrt[4]{8} = 0 $

I've calculated $ \Delta $ and it is something like this:

$ \sqrt[4]{4} + 4 \sqrt[4]{2} + 4 - 4 \sqrt[4]{8} $

I don't know what to do next.

Comment: What do you mean by $\Delta$?

Comment: Delta for the formula of the quadratic equation , $ \Delta = b^2-4ac $

Comment: @remember me it is the discriminant of the quadratic equation.

Comment: Okay. I had not seen that notation before.

Comment: I noticed numerically, that $\sqrt{2}$ and $2^{\frac{1}{4}}$ are the roots. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Use vieta : The product must be $8^{\frac{1}{4}}$ and the sum $2^{\frac{1}{2}}+2^{\frac{1}{4}}$

Answer (score 2):

Let us denote $a=\sqrt[4]2$. (Maybe this will help to notice how coefficients are related.)

We can rewrite the original equation as
\begin{align*}
x^2-xa(1+a)+a^3&=0\\
x^2-xa-xa^2+a^3&=0\\
x(x-a)-a^2(x-a)&=0\\
(x-a^2)(x-a)&=0
\end{align*}

This only has solutions $x_1=a$ and $x_2=a^2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $a=\sqrt[4]{2}$. So $a^3=\sqrt[4]{8}$. Now just use the quadratic formula